# Double curly braces are not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This code should evaluate the part in between the double curly braces according to a tutorial I'm following. I'm new to angularjs. So, pardon me if I'm asking silly question. Here's the link to plnkr  http://plnkr.co/edit/sFhDiA?p=preview

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script data-require="angular.js@2.0.0" data-semver="2.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-snapshot/angular2.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
            <script src="script.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body ng-app>
            <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
            <div> {{ 78 + 8 }} </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Wrong angular version http://plnkr.co/edit/ZrMV6c5Gs7EoDBaUqwpw?p=preview

Comment: Please post your **script,js** code. Where is your app (angularjs) code?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hackerman

Comment: @SharafatAhmedSabir I'm glad to help!

Comment: Nothing was is my "Script.js". Used CDN for angularjs. As Hackerman pointed out correctly, there was problem with my angular version.  @AsielLealCeldeiro

Answer (score 1):

You are missing your **ng-app** directive name on your html. Which means Angular won't run on your page.

Look into the ngApp documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp). You can get a clear idea from there!

Similar SO question is also available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599938/double-curly-braces-angularjs-dont-work)